# Adding a new case comment via Salesforce API C#

Tags: c#, api, salesforce

I'm working with the Salesforce Enterprise WSDL to manage Salesforce cases on a custom built C# web application. I've successfully been able to update the case owner however I can't figure out how to add a comment to the case. My code for updating the case owner is below. How do I add a new case comment?

```
    public void UpdateCase(SalesforceLogin currentLogin, String caseId, String userId, String newComment)
    {
        sfdcBinding.Url = currentLogin.ServerUrl;
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = currentLogin.SessionId;

        String query = "SELECT ID FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '" + caseId + "'";
        QueryResult results = sfdcBinding.query(query);

        if (results.records != null && !userId.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            SFDC.Case sfCase = results.records.Cast<SFDC.Case>().First();

            if (!sfCase.Id.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                sfCase.OwnerId = userId;

                SFDC.sObject[] toUpdate = new SFDC.sObject[1];

                toUpdate[0] = sfCase;
                sfdcBinding.update(toUpdate);

            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Code I'm using to add comments

```
public void AddCaseComment(SalesforceLogin currentLogin, String caseId, String userId)
{
        sfdcBinding.Url = currentLogin.ServerUrl;
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
        sfdcBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = currentLogin.SessionId;

        try
        {
            String query = "SELECT ID FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = '" + caseId + "'";
            QueryResult results = sfdcBinding.query(query);

            if (results.records != null && !userId.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                SFDC.Case sfCase = results.records.Cast<SFDC.Case>().First();
                if (!sfCase.Id.IsNullOrEmpty())
                {
                    CaseComment caseComment = new CaseComment()
                    {
                        CommentBody = "test",
                        ParentId = sfCase.Id,
                        CreatedById = userId,
                        IsPublished = true,
                        LastModifiedById = userId
                    };

                    SFDC.sObject[] toCreate = new SFDC.sObject[1];

                    toCreate[0] = caseComment;
                    sfdcBinding.create(toCreate);
                }
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the separate [CaseComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) object with the `ParentId` set to the target cases Id.

Comment: Ive tried that using the code I've added to my original comment.  The comment is never actually added and there are not errors thrown.

Comment: It turns out that it was erroring out because I was setting the user id(CreatedById = userId).  It worked when i removed that line of code.  Thanks!

Comment: @nsmanners Have you inspected the SaveResult that the create method returns? There is probably an error in there.

Comment: Great. The system will set the `CreatedById` and `LastModifiedId` fields for you.